# Implicit differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having trouble understanding how to solve this equation to find the general solution, it's obviously not homogeneous, separable or linear or exact so it must be implicit:

$2(\frac{dy}{dx})^3 + \frac{dy}{dx} - y = 0$

So I know I let $p = \frac{dy}{dx}$ then the equation becomes $2p^3 + p - y = 0$
I then derive that and it becomes $6p^2 \frac{dp}{dx} + p + \frac{dp}{dx} - \frac{dy}{dx} = 0$. What do I do then? I don't see how that would simplify down xD

Comment: Since you let $p=dy/dx$, that last equation you wrote down has some cancellation.

Comment: Why is there a $+p$? So there isn't cancellation, but it's still a separable equation for $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the D.E.
$$2 y' ^3 + y' - y = 0$$

Differentiate wrt x.
$$ 6 y'^2 y'' + y'' - y' =0$$

Rearrange
$$ (6y'^2+1)y'' = y'$$

$$ (6 y'+ \frac 1 {y'})y'' = 1$$

Integrate wrt x
$$ \int (6 y'+ \frac 1 {y'})y'' \operatorname{d}x = x+ c_0$$

Apply the chain rule $\int f(u(x))\frac{\operatorname{d}u}{\operatorname{d}x} \operatorname{d}x = \int f(u)\operatorname{d}u$
$$ \int (6 y'+ \frac 1 {y'}) \operatorname{d}y' = x+ c_0$$

Integrate wrt (y')
$$  3 y'^2 + \ln(y') = x+ c_0$$

Raise to the exponential
$$  y' e^{3y'^2} = c_1 e^x$$

Square and multiply by 6
$$  6y'^2 e^{6y'^2} = c_2 e^{2x}$$

$\because  z e^z = a \iff z= \operatorname{W}_n(a)$, the product log.

$$  6y'^2 = \operatorname{W}_n(c_2 e^{2x})$$

Divide by 6 then take the square root
$$  y' = \pm \sqrt{\frac16 \operatorname{W}_n(c_2 e^{2x})}$$

Integrate wrt x
$$ y = \pm \int \sqrt{\frac16 \operatorname{W}_n(c_2 e^{2x})} \operatorname{d} x$$

Substitute $e^x = u, \operatorname{d}x = u^{-1}\operatorname{d}u$
$$ y = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{6}} \int \frac1{u} \sqrt{\operatorname{W}_n(c_2 u^{2})} \operatorname{d} u$$

Substitute $c_2 u^2 = v, 2 c_2 u\operatorname{d}u = \operatorname{d}v$
$$ y = \pm \frac 1 2 \sqrt{\frac 1 6} \int \frac1{v} \sqrt{\operatorname{W}_n(v)} \operatorname{d} v$$

---

Given:

$$\frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}v} \operatorname{W}_n(v) = \frac{\operatorname{W}_n(v)}{v\operatorname{W}_n(v)+v}$$

Thus
$$\frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}v} \sqrt{ \operatorname{W}_n(v) } = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\operatorname{W}_n(v)}} \frac{\operatorname{W}_n(v)}{v\operatorname{W}_n(v)+v}$$

$$\frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}v} \sqrt{ \operatorname{W}_n(v) } = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\sqrt{\operatorname{W}_n(v)}}{v\operatorname{W}_n(v)+v}$$

Similarly

$$\frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}v} \operatorname{W}_n(v)^{\frac 32} = \frac 32 \frac{\operatorname{W}_n(v)^{\frac 32}}{v\operatorname{W}_n(v)+v}$$

So
$$\frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}v}\left(\frac{2}{3} \operatorname{W}_n(v)^{\frac 32} + 2 \operatorname{W}_n(v)^{\frac 12}\right) = \frac{\operatorname{W}_n(v)^{\frac 1 2}}{v}$$

---

$$ y = \pm \frac 1 2 \sqrt{\frac 1 6}  \int \frac1{v} \sqrt{\operatorname{W}_n(v)} \operatorname{d} v$$

$$ y = \pm \frac 1 2 \sqrt{\frac 1 6} \left(\frac{2}{3} \operatorname{W}_n(v)^{\frac 32} + 2 \operatorname{W}_n(v)^{\frac 12}\right) + c_3$$

Substitute $v=c_2 u^2, u=e^x \therefore v = c_2 e^{2x}$

$$ y = \pm \frac 1 3 \sqrt{\frac 1 6}\left(\operatorname{W}_n(c_2 e^{2x})+3\right) \operatorname{W}_n(c_2 e^{2x})^{\frac 12} + c_3$$

Done!